# R: ggplot2 geom_dotplot automatically adjust binwidth / out of plot window problem

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, visualization

I am trying to use geom_dotplot. In general it works good for smaller datasets. But I'd also like to use it for larger amounts of data.

When running with default binwidth settings (so not specifying binwidth at all) some of the points will just be cut on the y-axis.

Take this a example code:

```
df <- data.frame(input = c(rep(3,100), runif(200)))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = input)) +
  geom_dotplot(  binwidth = 0.015)
```

If I specify `binwidth` this works perfectly and I can see all points in the plot.

[image]

But if I use just standard settings without specifying `binwidth` like this:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = input)) +
  geom_dotplot( )
```

I get this plot:

[image]

Of course you could manually set binwidth each time. But I am looking for a solution, to automatically adjusts the binwidth (or some other parameter) in way that all points are displayed on the y-axis.

One of the problems is, that there is no reaction to commands like
`ylim(0, 50)` or  `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 2))`.

Probably related to this from the `geom_dotplot` documentation

> the numbers on y axis are not meaningful, due to technical limitations of
> ggplot2.

Was wondering if I maybe could use the "Computed variables" of geom_dotplot for this.
Something like **count**. Like you usually do with geom_histogram with after_stat.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / max(count))))
```

But it seems it doesn't work as input for binwidth ... seems to only work inside of aes()...?

Maybe there is even a more obvious solution I didn't think of.

Comment: You are right, probably the code was a little bit excessive ... tried to break it down to the key problem now.

Comment: I guess the reason is that each point will end up having an "absolute" rather than relative size. If you change the device size, this results in the dots being displayed. Still an interesting question how to automate that device size will be adjusted to bin width.

Comment: A workaround could be to not use `geom_dotplot`, but manually calculate the bins and use `geom_point` or even better `ggforce::geom_ellipse`. see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/61545633/7941188 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/61500224/7941188

Comment: Thanks for your help! I would of course have liked to prevent calculating everything on my own, but true on the other hand it solves all possible problems as it gives me control. geom_dotplot somehow seems to be one of the ggplot2 functions that still has room for improvement. I also saw multiple issues creating a meaningful y-axis that displays counts instead of arbitrary values from 0-1 that do not correspond to the dots.