# Geom_dotplot, y-axis showing counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a dotplot using geom_dotplot in which each dot represents an observation of my data set. Therefore, the y-axis shouldn't represent density but actual counts. I'm aware of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697235/ggplot-dotplot-what-is-the-proper-use-of-geom-dotplot) which revolves around the same topic. However, I haven't managed to solve my issue following the same methodology.

`df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:500, size = 150, replace = TRUE))`

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_dotplot(method = 'histodot', binwidth = 1)
```

And I obtain the following graph [image], I want to obtain one similar to this one [image: one] where I can manipulate dots' size, space between, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a starting point, is this closer to what you're looking for? `ggplot(df) + geom_dotplot(aes(x=x))`

Comment: Yes Christopher, it was a typo. Thanks

Comment: Each dot should represent an individual observation.  You can control the width of them with the binwidth argument.  By decreasing bindwidth, you get taller stacks of wider dots, but the total number of dots should be the same.  Unfortunately, the y-axis produced by geom_dotplot() is fully abstract as far as I can tell.  I've experimented with trying to scale it and set the limits manually (because geom_dotplot often does a poor job) but I can't figure it out.  I've had to settle for setting the y-axis limits manually.

Comment: Thank you Arthur. I have a better idea of binwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `binwidth` argument to cause the points to stack. For example,

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
  geom_dotplot(method = "histodot", binwidth = 20)
```

[image]

There is a `dotsize` argument that can be used to modify the size of the dot.

Comment: Thank you cazman, but with binwidth = 20 each dot doesn't represent an observation right.